# First telegram bot not responding to a slah command sent by antoher bot

Tags: python, chat, telegram, telegram-bot

I have quite a specific setup. I have a bot A and a bot B both in a same group. The bot A is responding to slash commands '/mail' sent in this group with some specific data regarding this email. This command works perfectly fine when I use it from my personal Telegram account.

I'm trying to use this existing behavior from a bot B. This bot B is sending /mail commands to the group with bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text="/mail test@gmail.com"). This message perfectly appears in the group chat.

However, the bot A doesn't seem to be triggered and never send data back.

Is there anything to specify in order to get the message interpreted as a command ? Is this possible ? Is there any privacy setting I missed ? I tried to play around with everything I found but I just couldn't figure out why this isn't working.

I'm using the python-telegram-bot to write bot B.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official Telegram's FAQ page says:

> Bots talking to each other could potentially get stuck in unwelcome loops. To avoid this, we decided that bots will not be able to see messages from other bots regardless of mode.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots